# Why did I get yearling badge twice in a day?

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two yearling badges on the same day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104465/two-yearling-badges-on-the-same-day)

I was quite pleased as my reputation crossed 200, and got my first silver badge `yearling` today morning. I was even more pleased as I got it *again* in the evening. I have gone through the various questions here about this badge, but they all seem to suggest that this badge is awarded once per *year*, not per *day*.

[image: Two yearlings in a day]

Comment: Wow, I searched for the exact same phrase `Two yearling badges on the same day`, and that did not show up on the whole of first page!

Comment: @ap. [Really?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=two+yearling+badges+on+the+same+day). First entry for me. Strange. Unless you don't order by relevance.

Comment: Well, never mind. I got the answer. It happened because I have been a member for over 2 years (though I only became active recently). I crossed 200 in the morning, and 400 in the evening.

Comment: Well done on that I'd say. ;)