# Yearling badge is confusing

Tags: support, badges

I just got my 3rd Yearling badge on SO. I have 602 points there. According to the description that means I got 200 points in a year 3 times. I have been active for 3 years and 4 months but just got my badge a few days ago when I broke 600. My question is does this mean that my 600 points were split exactly 200 points a year? How is it possible to be a user for 3 years and four months with exactly 600 points and get three badge? For example if I joined on Aug 2011 then lets say here is my point accumulation stats:

Aug 2011 - Aug 2012: 200 points, awarded badge.

Aug 2012 - Aug 2013: 200 points (total of 400), awarded badge.

Aug 2013 - Aug 2014: 150 points (total of 550), not awarded badge.

Aug 2014 - Dec 2014: 50 points (total of 600), awarded badge, why??

Comment: @Mureinik I agree. Not that the answer there would be a lot clearer (and certainly it's not true as it is written).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get your third yearling badge, you must:

- have been a member for at least 3 years
- have at least 600 rep

For some people, they get the badge on their anniversary because they have more than 600 rep before the three year mark. For others, it takes a little longer. If you had 101 rep after 3 years 1 month, then suddenly earned 500 more rep in a matter of weeks, you would earn three yearling badges within days of each other as you crossed each 200-rep multiple, or even on a single day as in [Why did I get yearling badge twice in a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158054/147247)

It does not matter when your rep was earned or at what pace. No process tracks how much rep you earned each year, though you can figure it out using graphs and the league pages.