# Received two Yearling badges within a week?

Tags: support, badges, yearling-badge

How come that I received two Yearling badges within a week (almost)?

[image]

Comment: It's basically a variant of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104465/369802): You've been a member of that site for 7 years now, and you've already got your first yearling badge (so you can skip the complicated calculation part). You'll get 1 badge for every 200 reputation points from now on, until you have 7 badges. Then, you have to earn 200 more points (for a total of 1600) and also wait until you're a member for 8 years before getting your 8th badge :)

Comment: thanks @Tinkeringbell for explanation, now I understand. In that case, the "Yearling" badge totally doesn't make sense... If it's this complicated, it signifies that something is wrong with the design. Good design is usualy simple and intuitive.